# Белый экран при авторизации, как выявить причину?

Tags: php, mysql

При авторизации белый экран, как выявить причину сего?
В таблице лежит лишь 1 пароль.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php

  include 'bd.php';

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT adminpass FROM adminpassword");
  $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);


  if(!empty($_POST['password'])){

    if($_POST['password']==$array[adminpass]){
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['access']=true;
      header("Location: adminpanel");
    }
    else {
       header("Location: error");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ?>

CONTENT...

<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69141/discussion-on-question-by-user273992-------).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы увидеть ошибки PHP можешь после `include 'bd.php';` поставить следующий код

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Но возможно у тебя проблема в mysql запросе.  Поэтому после вызова `mysql_query` поставь этот код чтобы увидеть mysql ошибку.

```
if(!$result) {
   print_r(mysql_error();
   exit;
}
```

Comment: если бы вы прочитали комментарии, то увидели бы, что проблем с запросом нет.

Answer (score -1):

Используй `pdo`, там вывод ошибок есть, примеры есть, и да у тебя не экранирован запрос, то есть защиты от иньекций нету, обычно ошибки выводятся так:

```
try {
....
} catch (Exception $e) {
....
}
```

Comment: в этом запросе и параметров нет, чтобы что-либо экранировать и инжектировать